# ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'account.invoice' in method

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to loop through all invoices I have but getting this error. if I change inv[0].id it works but loops only first invoice. how can i make it loop all invoices.

```
 def generate(self):
        Invoice = self.env['account.invoice']
        inv = Invoice.browse(Invoice.search([]))
        invoice = inv and inv[0]
        for inv in invoice:
            root = etree.Element('000')
            po_code = etree.SubElement(root, '22')
            po_code.text = str(inv.id) or ''
            return root

ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'account.invoice'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we call `self.env['account.invoice'].search([])`, we will be received a recordset of all records, that is stored in `account.invoice` model. Putting that recordset in the `browse` method again is redundant, as this method also returns a recordset. Moreover, it's not supposed to work because `browse` method expects from you an id or list of those. Check out documentation.

All you have to do from now is just to iterate over the recordset via `for` loop. At each time you will get one record from that recordset, so you can manipulate only it.

```
def generate(self):
    for record in self.env['account.invoice'].search([]):
        # go ahead with each record
```

Comment: with your example for loop takes only first invoice for some reason and stops after. and i have 50 of them.

Comment: If you're using the code from your question, then it's probably because you placed return statement in the body of your cycle. It will only iterate once and then return the root, that's for sure.